# Selecting points under polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, point-in-polygon

I have a point layer and a polygon layer (created from the point layer using local convex hull isopleths). I would like to be able to select only those points laying within the multiple polygons (all in same layer).

Is there a way to mask a point layer with a polygon layer?

Even if I can just select the points inside I can then export them to a new layer.

ArcMap 9.3.1

Answer (score 6):

You can select the points that fall within a polygon by using the Select By Location tool.
On the Main Menu toolbar, go to Selection>Select by Location.  You'll want to select features from your point layer are within your polygon layer.

Answer (score 1):

From the ArcMap menu: Selection-->Select By Location.