# How to query one shapefile using another shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, clip

How to query a shapefile using another shapefile in ArcGIS?

For example: I had one shapefile with states, another shapefile with towns. Now I want to query towns using the states file like towns of particular states.

Note: I can extract the data using *clip* , *union* or *intersect* tools in ArcGIS. Here, I don't want to extract data, I need to view the data.

Comment: ArcGIS has an option for joining or relating existing spatial objects (shapefiles and other). Your question is however a bit unclear on the purpose of your quest. I suspect that this question has already been answered in this forum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select points under polygons?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6600/select-points-under-polygons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "[select by location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000)". See the "selection" tab in the menu. This allows you to write query like 'town' is inside 'country'.